# Count Multidimensional Array always returns 1

Tags: objective-c

Regardless the number of items in my array, `count` always returns 1.
The `_contentData` array comes from Json response:

```
_contentData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:JSON, nil];
```

---

Array (_contentData):

```
    (
        (
            {
            id = 1;
            name = "Entry 1";
            },
            {
            id = 2;
            name = "Entry 2";
            },
            {
            id = 3;
            name = "Entry 3";
            }
        )
    )
```

Code:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)_contentData.count);
```

Output:

```
2013-04-26 18:32:00.968 SP[23542:c07] 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first object in your array is another array, so your count is always 1. Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[_contentData[0] count]);
```

Comment: Error: `Property 'count' not found on object of type 'id'`. The way I'm parsing Json to Array is correct?

Comment: Nope, just that the compiler doesn’t know that `_contentData[0]` is an array. I’ve edited the code, try the updated version.